# Pandas: How to merge columns containing the same name within a single data frame?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe extracted from an excel file which I have manipulated to be in the following form (there are mutliple rows but this is reduced to make my question as clear as possible):

```
        |A|B|C|A|B|C|
index 0: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

As you can see there are repetitions of the column names. I would like to merge this dataframe to look like the following:

```
        |A|B|C|
index 0: 1 2 3 
index 1: 4 5 6
```

I have tried to use the melt function but have not had any success thus far.

Comment: what if col A was repeated 3 times but C 0 times? or will every col repeat exactly once as your example?

Comment: In my specific use case each unique data column name will always repeat the same number of times, usually only twice. So I think the answer from @Ferran should always work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6]], columns = ['A', 'B','C','A', 'B','C'])
df
       A  B  C  A  B  C
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
pd.concat(x for _, x in df.groupby(df.columns.duplicated(), axis=1))
       A  B  C
    0  1  2  3
    0  4  5  6
```